# Is it safe to put Realm.Configuration into shouldRestoreApplicationState?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm implementing the app restoration features.
But I found that `viewDidLoad` is called before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets called.
And I have to read some data from database here.
So it always throws exception on `try! Realm()`.
Anyway, here's how I do it for now.

```
    var realmConfigured = false

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        configureRealm()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        print("restoring")

        configureRealm()
        return true
    }

    func configureRealm(){
        guard !realmConfigured else { return }

        realmConfigured = true

        let config = Realm.Configuration(...)

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    }
```

And it works fine so far.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What would you want that is 'better'? In general you don't want to access Realm objects before Realm has been configured so defer instantiating vars until after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Optionally Realm properties can be defined a `lazy` so you can instatntiate them any time but remember not to access them until after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: The main question is "Is it safe to put Realm.Configuration into shouldRestoreApplicationState?" I'm now working on restoration, but I have to read data from realm database in `viewDidLoad`. The restoration flow is a bit different from cold startup. `viewDidLoad` is called before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. So if I try to read data here, it'll throw exception. In the end I try to initialize realm in `shouldRestoreApplicationState`, then it will be initialized before it called `viewDidLoad`. But I don't know if it's safe to do that.

Comment: I think your question leads to another question: what are you trying to restore? The restore application state process is intended to restore *view hierarchies* and return the app to its original state - it sounds like you also want to restore custom objects. It's pretty specific and outlined in the Apple Documentation [Preserving Your App's UI Across Launches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches)

Comment: This issue even haven't touched the restoration. I have some customization preferences which is initialized in `viewDidLoad`. And these preferences are stored in realm database. It works fine when I opt-out restoration. But it starts throwing exceptions after I opt-in restoration. It all because the `viewDidLoad` is called before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the restoration flow. So I add the realm configuration to `shouldRestoreApplicationState` which is called before `viewDidLoad` then everything works fine again. I just not for sure if it will lead to another problem in the future.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @aehlke I don't have any official solution here. So I just put it there anyway. It works good so far.